# jQuery on select - multi select - change result in divs

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

I would like to have different results using jQuery in div after select/multi select change. There are two select inputs.

How to display at start all cars without tracks with no double? 
How to change results on car change to display available tracks
then change track to display available cars.
Or any different solution? The are some cars only available for certain tracks.

Example select:

```
<select id="cars" class="car-select">
    <option value="0">Choose a car</option>
    <option value="1">Car1</option>
    <option value="2">Car2</option>
</select>
<select id="tracks" class="track-select">
    <option value="0">All tracks</option>
    <option value="1">Track 1 Only for Car1</option>
    <option value="2">Track 2 Only for Car1</option>
    <option value="3">Track 3 Only for Car2</option>
    <option value="4">Track 4 Only for Car2</option>
    <option value="5">Track 5 Only for Car1</option>
</select>


<div id="results"></div>
```

Data to sort:

```
<div id="allcars">
<div class="Car1 track1">
<div>Car 1</div><div>Track 1</div></div>

<div class="Car1 track2">
<div>Car 1</div><div>Track 1</div></div>

<div class="Car1 track3">
<div>Car 1</div><div>Track 2</div></div>

<div class="Car1 track4">
<div>Car 1</div><div>Track 3</div></div>

<div class="Car2 track1">
<div>Car 2</div><div>Track 1</div></div>

<div class="Car2 track2">
<div>Car 2</div><div>Track 2</div></div>

<div class="Car2 track3">
<div>Car 2</div><div>Track 3</div></div>

<div class="Car2 track5">
<div>Car 2</div><div>Track 5</div></div>
</div>
```

Any JSfiddle examples please.

Comment: Create a fiddle on what you have done so far. Mention which multiselect you are using if any. If not then update the question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omaticomatic/d2jcyvam/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can tell, you meant you want to filter based on multiple select inputs.  UX-wise, it would be better to have the 2 selectors working together rather than the second overriding the car selection of the first.  [See this fiddle for functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/vtvuwjh5/1/).  Note that I have fixed the second selector, as they said "Truck" rather than "track".

JS:

```
$('#cars, #tracks').on('change', function() {
  function showall() {
    $('#results div').show();
  }

  var car_val = +$('#cars').val(),
    track_val = +$('#tracks').val();
  if (car_val === 0 && track_val == 0) {
    showall();
    return;
  }

  var selector = (car_val > 0 ? '.Car' + car_val : '') + (track_val > 0 ? '.track' + track_val : '');
  console.log(selector);

  $('#results>div:not(' + selector + ')').hide();
  $(selector).show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="cars" class="car-select">
  <option value="0">Choose a car</option>
  <option value="1">Car1</option>
  <option value="2">Car2</option>
</select>
<select id="tracks" class="track-select">
  <option value="0">All tracks</option>
  <option value="1">Track 1</option>
  <option value="2">Track 2</option>
  <option value="3">Track 3</option>
</select>


<div id="results">
  <div class="Car1 track1">
    <div>Car 1</div>
    <div>Track 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Car1 track2">
    <div>Car 1</div>
    <div>Track 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Car1 track3">
    <div>Car 1</div>
    <div>Track 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Car1 track4">
    <div>Car 1</div>
    <div>Track 4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Car2 track1">
    <div>Car 2</div>
    <div>Track 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Car2 track2">
    <div>Car 2</div>
    <div>Track 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Car2 track3">
    <div>Car 2</div>
    <div>Track 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="Car2 track5">
    <div>Car 2</div>
    <div>Track 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how to display before select only first divs - Car1. Car2 ?

Comment: I would use CSS, you can hide the divs on page load and show as required with the javascript.  What I normally do is create a class "hidden" (.hidden { display: none; }) and add/remove as required.

Alternatively, If you're always going to use the format above, you can do something like #result>div div:nth-child(2){ display: none; }